# Message:[/Resources/AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmHigh/Type/Dimensions/0/Value/Ref] 'null' values are not allowed in templates

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to implement amazon sqs in my current project. Currently with the help of Metric: **CPU Utilization**, Elastic beanstalk(EBS) server is deploying perfectly. But, when I'm trying to change the metric to **Request Count**, it it throwing **ERROR Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:[/Resources/AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmHigh/Type/Dimensions/0/Value/Ref] 'null' values are not allowed in templates**
[image]

Above is working fine
[image]

But this configuration is throwing error. Any leads are appreciated.